# Redux accessing state in another component

Tags: redux, react-redux, state, action, reducers

I'm having trouble accessing state in my components. I have one component (Add Page) where a user adds a 'name' and a 'weight'. What I would like to happen is for the 'name' and 'weight' that were added to be displayed on another component (Home Page) when the user clicks submit. When I console log the state in my home page, I get undefined. My DevTools shows that the state is updating with the added name and weight, but I can't figure out how to access it.
Here are my actions:

```
export const getMovements = (name) => {
    return {
        type: constants.GET_MOVEMENTS,
        name,
    }
};

export const addMovement = (name, weight) => {
    history.push('/')
    return {
        type: constants.ADD_MOVEMENT,
        name, 
        weight,
    }
};
```

Here are my reducers:

```
const initialState = {
    name: [],
    weight: [],
};

const addMovementReducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT:
            return { ...state, name: action.name, weight: action.weight }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const getMovementsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MOVEMENTS:
            return { ...state, name: action.name, weight: action.weight }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is my Add Page component:

```
const AddPage = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    console.log(name, weight);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title="Add Page" />
            <div className={classes.addPage}>
                <div className={classes.addMovementDiv}>
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.movementName} 
                        key="name" 
                        label="Enter Movement Name" 
                        InputProps= {{className: "textBoxColor"}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setName(value);
                        }} 
                         />    
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.movementWeight} 
                        key="weight" 
                        label="Enter Movement Weight" 
                        type="number" 
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={event => {
                            const { value } = event.target;
                            setWeight(value);
                        }}
                        InputProps= {{endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">lb</InputAdornment>, className: "textBoxColor"}} />
                    <Button 
                        className={classes.addButton}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={() => dispatch(addMovement(name, weight))}
                        >
                        <AddCircleIcon />
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.name,
        weight: state.weight,   
    }   
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return({
        addMovement: (name, weight) => dispatch(addMovement(name, weight))
    })
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(AddPage);
```

Here is my Home Page component:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const newMovements = props.name;

    return (
        <div>
            <Header title={"Home Page" }/>
            {newMovements}
            <div className={classes.fabDiv}>
                <Fab 
                    className={classes.fab}
                    onClick={() => history.push(`/add`)}>  
                    <AddIcon />      
                </Fab>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.name
    }  
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return({
        getMovements: (name) => dispatch(getMovements(name))
    })
};

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default compose(withConnect)(HomePage);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```js
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0);
```

which is non-Redux, component-local state, you would have to use your connected `props.name` and `props.weight`.

Since you are using function components and hooks, you can also use the [react-redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) `useSelector` and `useDispatch` which make this a lot easier than using `connect`.

So skip all the `connect`, `mapStateToProps` and `props.name` and just do

```js
  const name = useSelector(state => state.name)
  const weight = useSelector(state => state.weight)
```